# Logging before or after a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, debugging, logging

We are trying to get some knowledge how production environments are working with their logs.

Are they logging before any significant function:

```
logger.info("Deleting virtual machine. VMName: {}".format(vm.name))
vm.delete()
```

Or they are logging after any significant function:

```
vm.delete()
logger.info("Successfully deleted virtual machine. VMName: {}".format(vm.name))
```

Or they are using both but with 'debug' and 'info', as this person advised (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577523/6468443):

```
logger.debug("Deleting virtual machine. VMName: {}".format(vm.name))
vm.delete()
logger.info("Successfully deleted virtual machine. VMName: {}".format(vm.name))
```

Does anyone have **experience with logs**, and I'll just highligt that the will is to know how to do it **right and operationally**.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Should I log before or after an operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4577376/3357935)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question may opinion based. But I think this is interesting and worth discussing. In our products, we use several log levels so debug and info are typically here.

To answer your question about reporting before or after an action, it would depend on the action. In our case, for long actions we log before and after and try to use loading bars. With short actions, we only log before because if the action fails, an exception is raised so there is no reason to log after.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for sharing.
In long actions, you doing the debug/info method or they both info ? In short actions you log info before the action or debug ?

Comment: @JohnVendor for long actions we do info as the user need to know why he is waiting. For short ones it depends on the action. We do not want to pollute the user log so we only info the big steps. Here you have to compromise! Consider accepting to mark it answered :)

Comment: I would like to hear more opinions from other people.

Comment: @JohnVendor well now you won't as it has put on hold. As I said it is an opinion based question.